# Finding the Probability of a Conditional Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, random-variable, conditional-probability

I'm trying to answer the following question:

---

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent normal random variables with mean $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ respectively, and variance $\sigma^2_1$ and $\sigma^2_2$ respectively. Consider the random variables $Z= ({{X-\mu_1}\over{\sigma_1}})^2 + ({{X-\mu_2}\over{\sigma_2}})^2$. For arbitrary positive constants $a$ and $b$, find
$P(Z>a+b |Z>a)$

---

This confuses me because usually when finding the probability of standardized distributions, I would just take the RV as the center of an interval and then manipulate. But this conditional is confusing me. How to proceed?

Comment: So $Z$ does not depend on $Y$ at all?

Comment: Do you mean the $\chi^2_2$ variate $$Z= ({{X-\mu_1}\over{\sigma_1}})^2 + ({{Y-\mu_2}\over{\sigma_2}})^2$$In which case it is an exponential and hence memoryless variate.